# Determine final character in bash tabcompletion

Tags: python, bash, python-click

I'm looking to determine whether the final character is a space, or not.

```
$ mycli fl[TAB]  # no space
flag flare
$ mycli flare [TAB]  # yes space
A B C D
```

#### Reason

If it is a space, then the each argument is used to determine completion hints, but if it isn't a space, the former arguments will be used to determine a completion hint to the last. I just need to know which route to take in the Python script I'm using to compute the completion.

```
_mycli () {
  COMPREPLY=();

  local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
  local opts=$(mycli tabcompletion $COMP_LINE)
  COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${opts}" $cur))

  return 0
}

complete -F _mycli -o bashdefault mycli
```

It's probably out of scope for the question, here this is what part of the Python script looks like.

```
@mycli.command()
@click.argument("arguments", nargs=-1, required=False)
def tabcompletion(arguments):
    # Discard `mycli tabcompletion`
    arguments = list(arguments)[2:]

    complete = False
    if ???:
       complete = True
```

I'm looking to somehow determine (the ???-portion) whether an argument is finished, or whether to provide for completion to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space signals the end of the previous word and the beginning of a new word. Thus, `cur` will be `fl` in the first case and the empty string in the second.

Comment: Thanks, didn't see your reply until I had posted. I'll take a look at your this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Until something better comes along, here's how I got around it.

1. Strip the last item of `$COMP_LINE`
2. Pass item to the Python script
3. If item has a length of 1, it's assumed to be incomplete, e.g. dinosau[TAB]
4. Otherwise, it will have the length of a compete word, e.g. dinosaur

**Example**

```
_be () {
  COMPREPLY=();

  local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}

  if [ ${COMP_CWORD} -ge 2 ]; then
    if [ ${COMP_WORDS[1]} == "in" ]; then
      local opts=$(be tab $COMP_LINE ${COMP_LINE: -1})
      COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${opts}" $cur))
    fi
  fi

  return 0
}

complete -F _be -o bashdefault be
```

I don't fully understand it, and one of the limitations is that I cannot complete items consisting of a single character, which is not ideal, but ok for a prototype.